# Magento Wordpress integration - Fishpig not working properly

Tags: php, wordpress, magento

So, I have the following situation:
1. A fresh installation of Magento 1.6.1
2. A fresh installation of Wordpress 3.3.1

So, I installed module Fishpig through Magento Connect successfully but the Wordpress option in the admin panel of Magento does not show. Why and what can I do about that?!

Comment: I suggest, do installation by manually instead of connect. take wordpress extension via this site and check extension pack : [Direct download extensions](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things to try:

1. Check it's being picked up by Magento. Go into System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Advanced and check that the Fishpig_Wordpress extension is showing as Enabled. If it's Disabled, Enable it and you should be ok. If it's not showing, check that all of the extension files are in the right place. The main thing to check is that in /app/etc/modules there is a Fishpig_Wordpress.xml file and that the contents show that the Extension is active

   ```
   <active>true</active>
   ```
2. Check the permissions for the files are correct, check this [Magento Wiki page](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/magento_filesystem_permissions) to find out the correct permissions
3. Clear the Magento cache (as @Dick suggested).
4. If all else fails, remove it and do as @Oğuz suggested and install it manually

Answer (score 0):

If you're experiencing problems with the extension and can't figure out what's going on, feel free to drop us an email at help@fishpig.co.uk and we'll do our best to help you